# NLP Spacy add special case to recognize currency other than USD (ie. CAD)

Tags: nlp, spacy

I am doing a very simple task where I need to extract dollar amounts in a string.
I tried Spacy but it only recognize USD 1000 NOT CAD1000.
I tried adding a special case

```py
special_case = [{
        'ORTH': 'CAD', 
        'TAG': '$', 
        'IS_CURRENCY': True}]
nlp.tokenizer.add_special_case('CAD', special_case)
```

with no luck.

example:

```py
doc = nlp('I will pay you 1000 CAD tomorrow')
extracted_money = [ent.text for ent in doc.ents if ent.label_ == 'MONEY']
```

looking for a solution to return me `extracted_money =['1000 CAD']`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to extract these entities with spacy matcher? Or should it be solved with the tokenizer?

Comment: Hi Wiktor, I want to do it with spacy matcher. The tokenizer was the native first try with no success.

Comment: I posted an answer below, please feel free to drop a comment if you need anything clarified.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, works like a charm. I prob will add another pattern myself to accommodate both CAD 1000 and 1000 CAD. Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `spacy.matcher.Matcher`:

```py
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp('I will pay you 1000 CAD tomorrow')
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)  
pattern = [{'IS_DIGIT': True}, {'TEXT':'CAD'}] # NUMBER + CAD
matcher.add('CAD', [pattern])

matches = matcher(doc)
for match_id, start, end in matches:
    string_id = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]  # Get string representation
    span = doc[start:end]  # The matched span
    print( match_id, string_id, start, end, '->', span.text, '<-')
```

Output:

```
5189151114763691552 CAD 4 6 -> 1000 CAD <-
```

The pattern here is `[{'IS_DIGIT': True}, {'TEXT':'CAD'}]`: a number token followed with a `CAD` token.